# Robolectric shadow static inner class

Tags: shadow, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to unit test my code. I'm using reflection on android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.

```
Field[] fields = VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();
```

First element in this fields array is public java.lang.Object android.os.Build$VERSION_CODES.**robo_data** . I want to remove this field from fields array. I tried writing a shadow implementation for VERSION_CODES( a static inner class in android.os.Build)

```
@Implements(VERSION_CODES.class)
class ShadowBuildVersionCodes {
    public static final int BASE = 1;
    public static final int BASE_1_1 = 2;
    public static final int CUPCAKE = 3;
    public static final int CUR_DEVELOPMENT = 10000;
    public static final int DONUT = 4;
    public static final int ECLAIR = 5;
    public static final int ECLAIR_0_1 = 6;
    public static final int ECLAIR_MR1 = 7;
    public static final int FROYO = 8;
    public static final int GINGERBREAD = 9;
    public static final int GINGERBREAD_MR1 = 10;

    public void _constructor_ () {

    }
}
```

Also added this as config to my test-case

```
@Config(shadows={ShadowBuildVersionCodes.class})
```

This doesn't seem to work as fields array still shows public java.lang.Object android.os.Build$VERSION_CODES.**robo_data** as its first element. Please help me shadow this VERSION_CODES class.

Comment: Can you share code that you're testing?

Comment: Field[] fields = VERSION_CODES.class.getFields();

        for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
            Field aField = fields[i];

            try {
                int e = aField.getInt((Object)null);
                
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException var5) {
                var5.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: Yeah, clear. But what is the purpose?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work? Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that's not really possible.

`__robo_data__` (the name changed since the original question was asked) is one of the side-effects of Robolectric instrumenting the code.

Because of this, the best approach would be to ignore fields which aren't integers.